# Sometimes not receiving value through UDP Connection

Tags: java, android

I have established an udp connection in my application, but the problem is that sometimes it does not receive code from UDP Server function. It happens many times so there is any way to fixed out this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Note that UDP is **connectionless** protocol, there is no notion of connections in it.

Comment: Use TCP, it guarantees data transfer. UDP does not.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. When you use UDP there are no guarantees your message will reach the other side. Also, there is not really a "UDP connection", it is just discreet messages.

If you need a system which guarantees delivery, use TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Also UDP packet may return twice.
Use TCP, Luke